# Are there any open source PHP software for sending mass mail, i.e. newsletter?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, newsletter

I have used SendStudio in the past, but I am wondering if there is an open source version using LAMP?

Preferably, it should use a WYSIWYG editor for the emails, and be friendly on your *average* user.

Comment: Thanks for the spammer clarification ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.phplist.com/ is a good one I've used in the past.

Answer (score 3):

[poMMo](http://pommo.org/Main_Page) is a nice open source soft

Answer (score 2):

I use PHPList on my site.

Answer (score 1):

I've used PHPMailer successfully in the past.

Comment: PHPMailer is great, but it's a class, not a piece of software.

Answer (score 0):

Swift Mailer is also one of the best solution but it is library rather than application.